# Action is sometimes None in Django REST framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have written a customized permission class in Django REST Framework version 3.8.2 that behaves differently depending on the action of the request. I found that sometimes `view.action` is `None` when using the Browsable API to debug. Below follows a piece of code that will throw an exception when used with the Browsable API.

```py
class AdminOnlyPermission(BasePermission):

    def has_permission(self, request, view):

        # Just to demonstrate that view.action can be None
        assert(view.action is not None)

        # Only allow admin to delete
        if view.action == 'delete' and not request.user.is_staff:
            return False

        return True
```

What does it mean that `view.action` is `None`? Can I safely ignore it or is it possible for a malicious user to make a delete request with the action set to `None`?

**Edit:**

The permission class is only used for `GenericViewSets`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The viewset actions can't be **`None`**. If somewhat it became **`None`** during calling the views, viewset class will raise a **`TypeError`**.
According to the [DRF Source-Code](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/viewsets.py#L51),

> ```
> @classonlymethod
> def as_view(cls, actions=None, **initkwargs):
>     cls.suffix = None
>     cls.detail = None
>     cls.basename = None
>
>     # actions must not be empty
>     if not actions:
>         raise TypeError("The `actions` argument must be provided when "
>                         "calling `.as_view()` on a ViewSet. For example "
>                         "`.as_view({'get': 'list'})`")
> ```

The **`.as_view()`** method will called by **`URL Dispatcher`** whenever a matching regex pattern found in your **`urlpatterns`** list

> **Can I safely ignore it?**

Yes, **but** It completely depends on how you'd defined your view class. Which means, Suppose you have a custom action/method that accepts a GET method and delete your model instance, this permission class might not help you.
It can be helpful if you further customize the **`AdminOnlyPermission`** class.


You can use **`request.method=='DELETE'`** instead of **`action == 'delete'`** which is ***almost equivalant***

Answer (score 1):

I went through the similar issue with rest framework and permissions. And turns out these action are caused when the rest-framework's html forms send a `GET` and `OPTIONS` request to the server.

`...
  elif view.action is None and request.method in SAFE_METHODS:
      return True`

Had to fix as shown above. But I don't think this will be the case in production.